# Python - How do I find the x and y coordinates of the circle to create an arc on a map

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps

I am writing a python script that will map some points and curved on a map based on data that I receive. I am attempting to get the center coordinates of a arc/circle using any of the data that I receive below. I am having a hard time wrapping my brain around it.

- Point1 Lat and Lon
- Point2 Lat and Lon
- Starting Angle
- Ending Angle
- Radius Of the Circle

I do realize that I don't need all of this data to solve this.

I also have a flag that tells me if its a left or right hand turn.

Would getting the x and y cords be possible to calculate with the information I am receiving above.

I already have a function that is ran in javascript to draw the arc.

```
function drawArc(center, initialBearing, finalBearing, radius) {{
    var d2r = Math.PI / 180;   // degrees to radians 
    var r2d = 180 / Math.PI;   // radians to degrees 

    var points = 32; 

    // find the raidus in lat/lon 
    var rlat = (radius / EarthRadiusMeters) * r2d;
    var rlng = rlat / Math.cos(center.lat() * d2r); 

    var extp = new Array();

    if (initialBearing > finalBearing) finalBearing += 360;
    var deltaBearing = finalBearing - initialBearing;
    deltaBearing = deltaBearing/points;
    for (var i=0; (i < points+1); i++) 
    {{ 
      extp.push(center.DestinationPoint(initialBearing + i*deltaBearing, radius)); 
      bounds.extend(extp[extp.length-1]);
    }}
    return extp;
}}
```

I cant for the life of me find a good way to get the x and y coordinates of the center of the circle.

[image]

Comment: I would just like to note that it makes my brain upset that you have clockwise degrees as positive.

Comment: Several answers exist for this type of question in math.stackexchange.  [Example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27535/how-to-find-center-of-an-arc-given-start-point-end-point-radius-and-arc-direc).

Comment: Ill look into those answers right now. Seems like they may have what I need. Although some of it is still unclear.

Comment: @CoryKramer: Many graphics libraries define the "origin" as the top left corner of the screen and have the "y" axis point downward. In that case, it makes sense for clockwise to be positive degrees, because the whole graph is mirrored across the x axis from "traditional" axis orientation.

Comment: @JakeGriffin Interesting. I come from an engineering / physics background so I'm used to up/right/forward being positive, and CCW positive.

Comment: @CoryKramer: I am also from an engineering background, so I do understand your confusion. Your way makes more sense to me as well. I was just pointing out that reorienting things sometimes makes solutions simpler in certain situations. There are usually many valid solutions to any particular problem. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Given a point (Px, Py), that point's starting angle (Pa), and the radius (r), you can calculate the center (Cx, Cy) like so:

```
Cx = Px - r * cos(Pa)
Cy = Py - r * sin(Pa)
```

For example, if you want the center of the arc with a point at (1, 2) which is at Pi/3 radians (60 degrees) on a circle with radius 3, you can calculate the center like so:

```
Cx = 1 - 3 * cos(Pi/4) = 1 - 3 * 0.5 = 1 - 1.5 = -0.5
Cy = 1 - 3 * sin(Pi/4) = 1 - 3 * sqrt(2)/2 = -1.1213
C = (-0.5, -1.1213)
```

There are similar formulas you could use given other information as well. For example, you could calculate the center given a "first" and "second" point, the radius, and the "turn direction" (left or right). It is fairly simple trigonometry to derive these equations.

Comment: Does this work on a sphere map? My curves are randomly being placed on the map.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, center point doesn't depend on the parameters of the circle. It's XY coordinates on the canvas. It can be anywhere or oftener in the middle of the picture to look nicer.

Look here:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cairo, math

radius=100

starting_angle = math.radians(210) #  angle in radians
ending_angle = math.radians(330)

WIDTH, HEIGHT = radius*2+20, radius*2+20 # Canvas size

x=WIDTH/2 # X position
y=HEIGHT/2 # Y position


surface = cairo.ImageSurface (cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
context = cairo.Context (surface)

# Background Neutral Gray ----------
context.set_source_rgb(0.25, 0.25, 0.25)
context.rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
context.fill()


# Red Sector -------------------
context.set_source_rgb(1, 0, 0) # rgb color red
context.arc(x, y, radius, starting_angle, ending_angle)
context.line_to (x, y)
context.fill()


surface.write_to_png ("img.png") # Output to PNG
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying to get the arc between to points on a map. So I need to get the correct x and y coordinate based on the points. You have hard coded you center point based on the width and height of the canvas.

Comment: Well. I said center point can be anywhere. I suppose your map is flat in XY dimensions? I made my canvas around the circle since I don't have any map. Just find XY coordinates of the point on your map and make a circle

Comment: I got it. 2D is not quite applicable to 3D. Always something there to mismatch.